# What is the purpose of the "bootstrapping instance" in Juju?

Tags: cloud, amazon-ec2, juju

So I've recently played around with Juju, and I see quite a bit of potential. But there are a few things I don't exactly understand. Most notably, I'm not sure of the purpose of the "bootstrapping instance" (aka "bootstrapping node" or machine “0”).

Using the example from [the user tutorial](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/user-tutorial.html):

```
$ bin/juju status
machines:
  0: {dns-name: ec2-50-16-61-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com, instance-id: i-2a702745}
  1: {dns-name: ec2-50-16-117-185.compute-1.amazonaws.com, instance-id: i-227e294d}
  2: {dns-name: ec2-184-72-156-54.compute-1.amazonaws.com, instance-id: i-9c7e29f3}
services:
  mysql:
    formula: local:mysql-11
    relations: {}
    units:
      mysql/0:
        machine: 1
        relations: {}
        state: started
  wordpress:
    formula: local:wordpress-29
    relations: {}
    units:
      wordpress/0:
        machine: 2
        relations: {}
        state: started
```

Machine 1 is the mysql instance, and machine 2 is the wordpress instance. What exactly is machine 0 up to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bootstrap instance runs two critical pieces of the infrastructure: Zookeeper and the provisioning agent. Here is the architecture overview:

[image: Ensemble Architecture]

Right now this is actually a single point of failure.. though that will be solved in the near term by expanding the "bootstrap" service to 2 units either on demand, or in response to deploying a second machine. Luckily, Zookeeper is designed for high availability and the provision agent will use Zookeeper for coordination so its not a complex problem to solve, just one that needs to be solved before Juju is ready for real production usage.